# Returning the best match from my database given a list of booleans

Tags: postgresql

I hope this question is appropriate for this forum. I am setting up a PostgreSQL data base and need a few ideas on how to structure my tables so I can pull the data I need.

I know I need a table that contains information about different venues. There will be a column for the venue name and then several columns with details about the venue each containing a boolean. So for example column 1 will have the venue name, column two will be titled food and the data cell will either be true or false. There will be 15-20 columns.

I am going to get a list of user responses for each column (other than name) and want to return a list of venues ordered by best match.

Here is an example if I haven't been clear. I have a table with three entries:

```
Concert Hall, Yes, Yes, Yes
Opera, Yes, No, No
First Ave, Yes, Yes, No
```

I am receiving the user input which is `(No, No, No)`

My query should return:

```
Opera
First Ave
Concert Hall
```

It would be even better if I could get the % match as well: `(66%, 33%, 0%)`

Answer (score 1):

You need the appropriate `ORDER BY` clause:

```
SELECT venue_name
FROM venue_table
ORDER BY cast(boolcol1 IS FALSE AS integer) +
         cast(boolcol2 IS FALSE AS integer) +
         cast(boolcol3 IS FALSE AS integer) DESC;
```

The expression in `ORDER BY` will be 3 if all three boolean columns are `FALSE` and 0 if they are all `TRUE`.